# viewDidAppear runs after segue VC dismissed but not when VC presented by code is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a main VC that navigates to two other VCs in different ways. VC1 by a segue and VC2 using the code below. Both are dismissed in the same same way.

[image]

VC2 presented using:

```
viewController *nextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc2"];
nextViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Both VC1 and VC2 are dismissed in the same way when clicking Back:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
```

Main viewDidAppear runs when the VC1 is dismissed (the one presented by the segue) but not when VC2 is dismissed. Is there any way around this? I would like it to run when either of them are dismissed.

Comment: try `nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;` or `UIModalPresentationAutomatic `

Comment: Wonderful - so helpful. UIModalPresentationFullScreen did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Otherwise you need to set the presentation controller delegate and check for presentationControllerDidDismiss.

Comment: Why did you set `UIModalPresentationCustom` if didn't specify `transitioningDelegate`? And all additional parameters can be set in storyboard already.